# File Paths Are Too Long - Crashing FTP Transfers

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I am using licensed version of CuteFTP to transfer files(Thousands in number) for one server to another.

The problem I am facing now is most of the FTP transfers are failing as File Paths Are Too Long.

On average, the character length of my file path would be anywhere between 200 & 250.

I cannot individually shorten the file titles manually as there are huge number of files.

Any ideas or suggestions to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is an limitation of Windows more specifially the NTFS File system. The MAX_PATH define does allow you to create files with a total (path and file name) length of 260 characters. The easy way is to use Robocopy which can deal with such file names or if you are bound to FTP you will get an error when the target file name is too long. The only easy way out of this is to create a zip file the the files in question and transfer the zip file. This should be a good idea anyway since the transfer over the wire is much slower than to simply stream one big file which is 2-4 times smaller than the original data.

As bonus you get rid of the long file names until you try to unpack them. But then you should choose your folder structure in a way to have a shallow root directory.

Comment: I cannot zip the files as I am transferring my video files to a CDN(Highwinds) from which the video streaming is provided. So the folder\file structure has to be maintained.